# Spservices getlistitems managed metadata column

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spservices

I have a regular custom list with all sorts of data but the one that's not working with the spservices getlistitems is the managed metadata field.

I am getting undefined when I tried to use ows_documentname .

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the capture about the metadata field value format, it will like "ID;#Label":
[image]

Please split this like:

```
$(this).attr("ows_metadata").split(";#")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the managed metadata field will be returned in the `ID;#Value` format.

So, you need to split it using javascript `split` function as below. Here, the internal name of managed metadata column is `Test`:

```
$(this).attr("ows_Test").split(";#")[1]
```

Modify the code as per your column internal name.

The full code that i used is:

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "Documents",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
                console.log($(this).attr("ows_Test").split(";#")[1]);
            });
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I was doing the same but I had the wrong internal name from site template site.

Your solutions are correct.